# Help with preimage and image sets of a given function

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Consider the function $$f:\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7\} -> \{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9\}$$ given as $$f={(1, 3), (2, 8), (3, 3), (4, 1), (5, 2), (6, 4), (7,6)}.$$

The question asks me to find(questions along with my answers):

$$1. f(\{1, 2, 3\}) = \{3, 8, 3\}$$

$$2. f(\{4, 5, 6, 7\}) = \{1, 2, 4, 6\}$$

$$3. f(\emptyset)  = \emptyset$$

$$4. f^{-1}(\{0, 5, 9\}) = \emptyset$$

$$5. f^{-1}(\{0, 3, 5, 9\}) = \{1, 3\}$$

Am I on the right track?

Comment: don't you have $f(5)=2$?

Comment: Answers look good, except for the first one. A *set* only contains *unique* elements, so that would be $\{3,8\}$.

Comment: Ahh! Right. Forgot my basics there. Thank you!

Comment: How is $f^{-1}$ defined here? $f$ isn't a bijection.

Comment: @ShraddheyaShendre $f^{-1}(A)=\{x\in I_7\mid f(x)\in A\}$, is called the pre-image of a set $A$. I'm calling the domain $I_7$. If $f$ is a bijection the preimage of A and the image of the inverse map of A will agree.